# MySQL multiple LIMIT statements

Tags: mysql, limit

I have this select statement:

```
SELECT a.nameid, b.nameid, c.nameid, d.nameid 
FROM myTable AS a, myTable AS b, myTable AS c, myTable AS d 
LIMIT 10,20;
```

But this code pulls the same exact limit range of numbers for each new column, I would like each column to have a different LIMIT range. For example I would like myTable AS a to have LIMIT 1,3 and myTable as d to have LIMIT range 3,5;

what I have:

```
nameid
-------
joe1
joe2
joe3
joe4
joe5
joe6
joe7
joe8....joe 30

RESULTS SHOULD BE:
result a   result b   result c
--------   --------  ----------
joe1       joe4      joe7
joe2       joe5      joe8
joe3       joe6      joe9
```

Comment: Can you show a small example of data and your intended result? I am guessing you want several subsets of rows, but you seem to be using old-style JOIN syntax.

Comment: Wouldn't a `UNION` be what OP is looking for?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 
 [**Tips better SQL Question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056)

Comment: The query you have delivers all possible combinations of four `nameid` values. You're using old-style comma JOINs without any constraints, so SQL just generates all possible combinations.  So if you have ten rows in your table, you'll get 10,000 rows in this result set.  With 100 rows in your table, you'll get 10**8 (a hundred million) rows. It seems unlikely that's what you want. Your `LIMIT` clause cuts that down to just some of those rows.